# How can I write a Python function that will only accept a list with int or float type inside?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, types, integer

I need to write a function which will take a list with int or float types. If there will be a nested list, the function must return "No", and if there will be only float or int types, the function must return "Yes".
Here is my code

```
def take_list(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list) is True:
            return "No"
        elif isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float):
            return "Yes"


print(take_list([1, 2, [3, 2]]))
print(take_list([1, 2, 3, 2]))
```

But here is the answer is always "Yes".
I tried "type" instead of "isinstance", so it doesn't work

Comment: Put `print(i)` under `for i in lst:`. How many print outs do you get?

Comment: Printed, the program says `1`

Comment: Ya. If you don't get any more print outs, what does that mean? (Think about where you're `return`ing).

Comment: I guess it means that I work only with 1 object on the external level (`lst`). But I still don't get it :(

Comment: You're always `return`ing in the first iteration of the loop. Every path the code can take in that loop will end in either `return "No"` or `return "Yes"`, and as soon as you `return`, you exit the function. Does it make sense to return `"Yes"` before you've checked the entire list?

Comment: @Ruslan You know there are more elements in your list, but something is causing it to end after the first element. What part of your function could be ending the loop?

Comment: Okay, perhaps I got what you mean. I need to loop through each element of the list, not loop through each element of my function, because there is only one element. I need to use `for i in range` constuction, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. The `for i in lst:` is fine. I'd set it up so that you return "no" in the loop as soon as you find a bad element, but then return "yes" *after* the loop. If you make it through the entire loop without returning, then you know that all the elements are good, since you would have returning earlier if there were a bad element.

Comment: Yeah, now it works, good!

Answer (score 1):

what about using `type`?

```
def take_list(lst):
    # if all(isinstance(item, (int, float)) for item in lst): # another way
    if all(type(item).__name__ in ['int', 'float'] for item in lst):
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"


print(take_list([1, 2, [3, 2]]))     # No
print(take_list([1, 2, 3, 2, 1.2]))  # Yes
```

`type` is a function in `int` and `float` classes, use `___name___` to get the classes names.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I added another way using `isinstance`. I don't have any reason behind using `type`. But what do you mean by "red herring"?

Comment: I mean that suggesting to use `type`, which is the focus of your answer, doesn't actually solve their problem. If they changed their original code to use `type` instead of `isinstance`, they'd have the same issue that they do now. The actual solution is your use of `all`, which you never mention.

Comment: @Carcigenicate , I am suggesting to use `type` instead of using many `or`: `if isinstance() or isinstance() etc.`. Then I added another way to use `isinstance` with multiple class types.